# Is there a gui for writing dockerfiles?

Tags: user-interface, docker, virtual-machine

I'm looking for an easy-to-use GUI for the creation of a dockerfile, without actually being familiar with docker statements.

Ideally it would include a "drag and drop" interface where I could put files from my personal computer into the container.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only gui tool related to docker that I know is [Kitematic](https://kitematic.com/), but as far as I know it doesn't build dockerfiles.

Comment: vim, emacs, atom, nano, gedit are GUI tool to build Dockerfile. There are very easy to use though the frist two ones require a bit of learning to start from scratch :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no GUI for creating Docker containers.

This is probably because there's not much to it. The things you need to know (experience with shell commands, Unix systems, Dockerfile commands and the way Docker images/containers work) would mostly still be necessary if you were using a GUI. Dockerfiles are little more than shell commands, making a GUI for those isn't really necessary.

Docker containers are more than just a bunch of files. Even with drag'n' drop, you'd be writing shell commands by hand.

It's not such a bad idea. I'd like to see what someone could create to this ends. But I'd probably go back to doing it by hand myself ;)